# Bootstrap. "Отзывчивая" таблица

Tags: html, bootstrap

Господа хорошие, гуру и монстры бутстрапа, подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно поменять в коде, чтобы таблица нормально отображалась не только на компьютере, но и на экране мобильника.
В шаблон "ArchitectUI HTML Theme Dashboard - v4.0.0" вставляю таблицу, она неплохо выглядит на компьютере, но совсем не влезает в ширину экрана мобильника
[image: Так выглядит при ширине экрана компьютера]
[image: А так - при ширине экрана мобильника]
При средних точках останова - всё, более-менее, читабельно.
Прошу простить, что код может оказаться длинным - не знаю, что нужно оставить, чтобы было понятно, а что нафиг не нужно )))

[ссыль на страницу в github](https://idontremembermyname.github.io/lessons/)

вот, пробую добавить скрин того, что выводит мобильник при добавлении в класс table-responsive-xs
[image: table-responsive-xs]

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#responsive-tables

Comment: @Dias, т.е., как я понимаю, в данном случае, без горизонтальной прокрутки на мобильнике не получится?

Comment: @Dias если я правильно понял, то лучше, вообще, отказаться от table и сверстать таблицу на div-ах?